# Error while using imagecreate function

Tags: php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/png");

$im = @imagecreate(110, 20) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);

imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

When i executed the above code i have  got an error like this

"The image  can't be displayed because it contains errors "

Same error shows in server also

Comment: *Some error shows in server also*. Care to add this detail to your question? What do you see if you omit the `header()` call?

Comment: when omitted the header,there is an error in the page

Comment: Also, your code works fine in [my test](http://goo.gl/uZWW5)

Comment: cannot reproduce either http://codepad.viper-7.com/dsdZG8

Comment: Your code works fine for me. http://vdev.info/image_test.php

Comment: But i have the same error in server and local

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess you have some sort of content before and / or after your PHP tags.

Make sure your file starts with `<?php` with **nothing** before it (you may need to check for a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

Also, omit the closing `?>` tag. You don't need it and it will solve any trailing whitespace issues.